# Unstably dualizable maps

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, smooth-manifolds

Call a map between compact, connected framed $n$-manifolds $f:M \rightarrow N$ unstably dualizable if there exists an $f':N \rightarrow M$ such that the following diagram commutes up to homotopy:

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\Sigma^\infty_+ N @>{f'}>> \Sigma^\infty_+ M\\
@V\simeq VV @V\simeq VV \\
\Sigma^n N_+^\vee @>{f^\vee}>> \Sigma^n M_+^\vee
\end{CD}$$

Because $\bar{H}_0(M_+)\xrightarrow{f}\bar{H}_0(N_+)$ is an isomorphism, $f'$ is forced to be an isomorphism in dimension $n$. Reversing the roles, $f$ is also forced to be an isomorphism in dimension $n$. From Poincare duality, one can deduce that $f$ is a homology isomorphism. Hence, if $M,N$ are simply connected, we can conclude that any unstably dualizable map is a homotopy equivalence.

$\bf{Q}:$ Is this true if we remove the simply-connected hypothesis?

Note: In the case $M=N$ and $\pi_1(M)$ is Hopfian, i.e. every surjective group endomorphism is an isomorphism, the result is true. A degree 1 map has to be surjective on the fundamental group and thus an isomorphism. We can then replace the above diagram by one of the universal covers of $M$ (which will need some compactifications if $\pi_1(M)$ is infinite) and use the same reasoning as above to get a homotopy equivalence of universal covers.

Comment: Taking the S-dual of the universal cover is probably not the correct thing if $\pi_1$ is not finite.  Rather, it makes more sense to take the $S$-$\pi$-dual in the sense of Ranicki (cf. section 3 of https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/ats2.pdf ).

Comment: Isn't the constant map $M \to N$ unstably dualizable by the constant map$N \to M$? Or am I mistaken? If I am not mistaken, then that would contradict your conclusion about the map being a homotopy equivalence.

Comment: @JohnKlein The constant map is an isomorphism in bottom degree homology, its dual with then be an isomorphism in top degree homology, so the constant map is not dual to the constant map. For example, the dual of the constant map $M \rightarrow S^n$ is represented by the Pontryagin-Thom collapse map $S^{n+c} \rightarrow \Sigma^c_+ M$.

Comment: The easiest example of unstably dualizable maps are framed diffeomorphism; then $f'=f^{-1}$ and the commutativity of the square is implied by the framing being preserved.

Comment: I see...........